# What's an easy way to see what AJAX calls are being made?

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging, xmlhttprequest

I'm looking for something (preferably a Firefox extension) which will allow me to see all AJAX subrequests.  Basically, anytime an XMLHTTPRequest() is made, I want to know what URL was being requested and what (if any) GET and POST vars were passed along with it.

Unless I'm missing it, I don't see anything quite like this in Firebug or Web Developer Toolbar.

*(In case you're curious, the main reason for wanting this is that I want to scrape a local copy of a site that is using JS to load all its contents, and I don't want to spend hours digging through their JS code when I could just see the subrequests being made.)*

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) should show it in the Net panel.

**EDIT**: Also, if Firebug slows down your Firefox in a way that makes it unusable, like it does for me sometimes, [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (formerly Ethereal) will analyze all network traffic on your system, including HTTP and AJAX requests.

Answer (score 10):

[Fiddler 2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a great tool for watching HTTP traffic.

*** 2014 Update ***

Since my original post, both Internet Explorer and Chrome have added built-in developer tools that are quite useful. While I still support and use Fiddler for non-web related http monitoring or when I need to really dig in deep and modify requests in transit, these days I find myself pretty much using IE or Chrome's built in tools as they are sufficient for 99% of my needs. They both have a networking tab, where you can monitor http requests, plus other nifty features for debugging webpages.

- [Internet Explorer F12 Tools Introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589512(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Documentation for Chrome's F12 Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)
- [FireBug, which is mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/911214/86860) is also a good tool if you're using FireFox.

Comment: It maybe worth mentioning that Firefox now also has its own built-in developer tools without the need to install an add-on. To view network requests push Ctrl-Shift-Q.

Answer (score 7):

I have used nearly all the big tools out there (fiddler, firebug, httpfox, live http headers). The best one in my opinion is [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647) if you are using Firefox because it has easy filtering capabilities, allows you to view your JSON the request/response as raw or formatted and the over all interface is very clean.

Also, I can't do without [WFetch](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=b134a806-d50e-4664-8348-da5c17129210&displaylang=en) for testing web services and AJAX stuff. Usually I'll take the request from HTTPFox and paste it into WFetch. This way I don't have to go through the browser each time. I just hit F5 in WFetch to replay the request and I directly modify the request.

Side note: In WFetch, be careful about content-length if you have a POST payload. If you modify the payload the content-length needs to be changed as appropriate. For this reason I save my requests in a file and point WFetch to the file. In the file itself it is easy to know the length of the line and change content-length to that.

[image]
<sub>(source: [koreus.com](http://blog.koreus.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/httpfox.png))</sub>

[alt text http://www.port80software.com/assets/images/ld_wfetch3.gif](http://www.port80software.com/assets/images/ld_wfetch3.gif)

Answer (score 6):

Firebug shows them in both the Net panel, and the Console view. You need to turn on "Show XMLHttpRequests" though.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Tamper Data as well. It's a Firefox add-on that lets you have a look at each individual HTTP request (including any post data) and response, and the headers of both. I've found it very useful for debugging AJAX problems...although Firebug works just fine.